# Storybook problem while migrating argument of type object from addon-knobs to addon-controls

Tags: arguments, storybook, stenciljs

I'm having some trouble migrating one thing from the old `addon-knobs` to the new controls. Let me explain, maybe it's not such difficult task but I'm blocked at the moment.

I'm using StencilJS to generate Web Components and I have a custom select component that accepts a `options` prop, this is an array of objects (the options of the select)
So, the story for this component in the previous version of Storybook looks something like this:

```
export const SelectWithArray = () => {
  const selectElement = document.createElement('my-select');
  selectElement.name = name;
  selectElement.options = object('Options', options);
  selectElement.disabled = boolean('Disabled', false);
  selectElement.label = text('Label', 'Label');
  
  return selectElement;
};
```

This works fine, the select component receives the options property correctly as an array of objects.
Now, migrating this to the new Storybook version without `addon-knobs`, the story is looking like this:

```
const TemplateWithArray: Story<ISelect> = (args) => {
  return `
    <my-select
      label="${args.label}"
      disabled="${args.disabled}"
      options="${args.options}"
    >
    </my-select>
  `;
};

export const SelectWithArray: Story<ISelect> = TemplateWithArray.bind({});

SelectWithArray.argTypes = {
  options: {
    name: 'Options',
    control: { type: 'object' },
  }
}

SelectWithArray.args = {
  options: [
    { text: 'Option 1', value: 1 },
  ]
}
```

And with this new method, the component is not able to receive the property as expected.
I believe the problem is that now, the arguments is being set directly on the HTML (which would only be accepting strings) and before it was being set on the JS part, so you could set attributes other than strings.

Is there a way to achieve this? without having to send the arguments as a string.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

One way I've discovered so far is to bind the object after the canvas has loaded via the `.play` function;

```
codeFullArgs.play = async () => {
  const component = document.getElementsByTagName('your-components-tag')[0];
  component.jobData = FullArgs.args.jobData;
}
```